# SQL left outer join with where condition

Tags: sql, left-join, outer-join

I am new to SQL and learning joins.

Please consider the two queries below:

When I run the first query below:

```
select count(*)
from products p 
left outer join order_details_v od 
on p.product_id = od.order_item_product_id
```

Returned count value is **12332**

But when I am this second query:

```
select count(*)
from products p 
    left outer join order_details_v od 
    on p.product_id = od.order_item_product_id
    and to_char(od.order_date::timestamp, 'yyyy-MM') = '2014-01'
```

Returned count value is **1224**

Why is the count is different in the second query? I understand that we have added an additional condition in the join, but since it is a left outer join, it should keep all the rows of the left table and therefore count should be same. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Presumably there is more than one `order_detail` for a given `product` - the second query restricts how many orders are returned for a given product, hence you get less rows.

Comment: Try getting the full registers and not just the count. Does the difference occur, as @GMB suggests, precisely in cases where there are multiple entries of order_details for a single product?

Comment: `count(*)` does not counting the rows on the left, but all the rows resulting from the outer join. Therefore, the counts are different.

Comment: Such questions can easily be answered on your own by adding further restrictions and so fetch just 5 or 10 entries, so the difference becomes obvious.

Comment: `Why is the count is different in the second query?` Well, you put additional filtering (order in Jan 2014) in the second query.  Of course the result will be much less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the query from Count(*) to * you can easily inspect what is occurring.

Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the additional filter on the order date will always return at least one row for each of the products.  Additionally, each product that had orders on 2014-01 will likely have multiple lines for an order.  That will expand the count of rows needed to report the product.

As you learn more about SQL, explore more SQL commands to examine results.  If you add Select COUNT (DISTINCT p.product_id) to your query you'll notice that the count remains the same.

Your SQL returns the COUNT(products where the product order date is null) + SUM(product detail counts where the order day is  2014-01)

One additional point beginners don't realize is if you add the restriction to a where clause instead of the on clause such as Select ... from  ... **Where order day is '2014-01'** your result will behave like an inner join and only products that have been ordered on the day will be returned.  The data with null values in the order date of the right side of the join were null after the outer join, but in the where clause null does not equal order day is '2014-01.  So all of those records are removed instead of reported.

Good luck as you learn the language.

Answer (score 0):

The count has been reduced to 1224 as there is also an additional filter "and to_char(od.order_date::timestamp, 'yyyy-MM') = '2014-01'"
Filter of this order_date column has accounted only those specific rows out of the join result set and gave you different number count.
Hope this helps.